# Getting error in running dynamically compiled C# code

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I compiled a c# code dynamically in a `.Net Core 3.1` project. I saved the result as a `.dll` file and trying to use it in another project. In destination project when I add it as a reference and trying to use, I get this error

> `the type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0`.

I tried to compile the code as `netstandard 2.1`. And also there is reference to `System.Private.CoreLib` during the compilation in `_references` but the version is newer than `4.0.0.0`.

```
_references = new List<MetadataReference>();
_references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location));
_references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load("netstandard, Version=2.1").Location));
 _references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location));
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference to the netstandard library, which doesn't technically define any types, to match your `typeof(object)`.

```cs
    var netstandard = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.GetName().Name == "netstandard").Single()
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have it in my references `_references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.Load("netstandard, Version=2.1").Location));`

Comment: You said 3.1 in the question, so your typeof(object).Assembly would be incompatible.

Comment: I said `.Net Core 3.1` and the related `.Net Standard` is `2.1`

Comment: Still, since you are implicitly referring to the typeof(object).Assembly that is loaded in your process. It makes sense that you should also refer to the compatible netstandard Assembly that you are also currently using. Avoiding any magic numbers that may be incorrect.

Comment: You are right. I tried that without version number and still get same error.